# COPY command not found in postgres dockerize

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to COPY data from CSV to container

From postgres container shell

```
$COPY
copy command not found
```

also tried \copy

but createdb and dropdb works for me.

Answer (score 2):

`COPY` is not a `bash` shell command, it's a command run within the `psql` database query shell.